# XQuery How to filter the elements in xml before parsing data without using loops or pipeline

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql, xmltable

hello i have xml say like this for example

```
<row>
<c1>a</c1>
<c2 >b</c2>
<c3>c</c3>
<c4>d</c4>
<c4 @m=2>d2</c4>
<c5>e</c5>
<c6>f</c6>
</row>
```

here's my Query

```
SELECT XT.*
                FROM table1  X,
                XMLTABLE ('/row/*'
                 PASSING X.XMLRECORD
                 COLUMNS    MV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@m)',
                            SV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@s)',
                            TAG_NAME VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'name(/.)',
                            VALUES_ VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH '.') XT
```

so my target table should be like this

```
MV   SV   TAG_NAME   VALUES_
null null   c1          a
null null   c2          b
null null   c3          c
null null   c4          d
2    null   c4          d2
null null   c5          e
null null   c6          f
```

what i want to do is to take only tags `c4,c5,c6`
i mean to filter it before parsing the data not after
i tried using loops like this

```
SELECT XT.*
                FROM table1  X,
                XMLTABLE (for $x in'/row/*'
                 where 'name(/.)' in ('c4','c5','c6')
                 PASSING X.XML
                 COLUMNS    MV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@m)',
                            SV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@s)',
                            TAG_NAME VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'name(/.)',
                            VALUES_ VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH '.') XT
```

but it took a lot of time due to massive number of data
i also tried this

```
SELECT XT.*
                FROM table1  X,
                XMLTABLE ('/row/c4|/row/c5|/row/c6'
                 PASSING X.XML
                 COLUMNS    MV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@m)',
                            SV NUMBER PATH 'data(/./@s)',
                            TAG_NAME VARCHAR2 (100) PATH 'name(/.)',
                            VALUES_ VARCHAR2 (1000) PATH '.') XT
```

but same problem it took a lot of time also bec massive number of data if there's a way to filter before parsing without using 2 solutions i just showed you

Comment: Please provide a well-formed XML. Your XPath expressions don't match the provided XML sample.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and  its version.